# NSURLConnection with delegate vs initWithContentsOfURL: with Grand Central Dispatch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, nsurlconnection, grand-central-dispatch

I am writing an application which downloads very much JSON data from the internet. My app needs to parse this JSON data and afterwards return the retrieved objects to a self-made delegate.

Now I was wondering if I could better use NSURLConnection or a combination of Grand Central Dispatch's `dispatch_async` with `initWithContentsOfURL:` (using GCD to prevent hanging).

Using Grand Central Dispatch is **much** easier to implement, especially because I don't need delegates nor NSMutableData nor all other variables that are used temporarily. But of course, everything with pros has its cons.

What are the advantages of NSURLConnection over `initWithContentsOfURL` with GCD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can target iOS 3.x.
2. You can use a customized NSURLRequest that, e.g., asks for the results of an HTTP POST—the NSData factory only does basic GET when passed an HTTP URL.
3. You can track the download's progress with your NSURLConnection delegate.

That's it off the top of my head. :)

Comment: I'm reading the JSON data from a read-only source, so I don't need POST, and I don't see a reason people are still using iOS 3. :)

Comment: Then apart from progress tracking, there's not really any benefit to you. Use GCD and your code stays clean. :)

Comment: There is another advantage. When using NSURLConnection with delegate, you are able to cancel connection any time. Using GCD you can only provide flag in block that will be checked during block execution, but no connection cancellation possible.